# PHP I have a database connect file, should i put my database querie functions in the same file

Tags: php, database, mysqli, database-connection

to explain my question better, i have two files: dbh.inc.php

```
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "xxxxx";
$dbPassword = "secret";
$dbName = "databasename";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$table1 = "users";//1
$table2 = "userprofile";//2
$table3 = "twofactorauth";//3
```

And: database-query.func.php

```
function selectdb($data, $values, $url) {
  include ('dbh.inc.php');
  extract($data);
  extract($values);
  switch ($data['table']) {
    case '1':
    $table = $table1;
    break;
    case '2':
    $table = $table2;
    break;
    case '3':
    $table = $table3;
    break;
  }
  $sql = "SELECT $rows FROM $table WHERE $where;";
  print_r($sql);
  die();
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header("Location: ".$url."?error=sqlerror");
    die();
  } else {
    $amount = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $values = array_values($values);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $amount, ...$values);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    $new = array_push($getResult, 'true');
    return $getResult;
  }
}
```

So the first holds database connection, and the latter has dynamic querys for insert, update and select for the moment. And i am wondering should i combine the two files, to one. Since every time i need my connect i always use one of my querys and same on the other way around?

Also 2 bonus questions: as you see in my connect file i have my table names and i use numbers in my other files and in the functions connect numbers to names.
Lastly should i use PDO, why?

Comment: Thats an awful way of doing this for more than one reason

Comment: One being that this will cause you to open a connection for each and every query in a script. That is comparatively a slow process

Comment: Why obfiscate the table names by giving them numbers? All that will do is make maintenance difficult

Comment: It would appear that using this you can only ever return one result row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question in general - yes, you can put a helper function in the same file where sql connection is made.

However, the code of your actual function is questionable at the very least. Or, to tell you truth, your function `selectdb()` is a *torture* for a programmer and shouldn't be stored *anywhere*. Stick to natural SQL queries written as is. You don't need numbers to represent tables. You don't need $rows variable. Everything could be written right in the SQL string. All you will need is a simple helper function that would reduce the amount of code required to run a query.

Here is an example of such [mysqli include file](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#include)

Once it's included in in your script, you can use it to run any mysql query, to any table, with any list of variables. Check out the following example (you can copy and paste the following code block to your file and run it as is):

```
<?php
require 'mysqli.php';

#Create a temporary table
$conn->query("CREATE temporary TABLE tmp_mysqli_helper_test
              (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(9))");

# populate it with sample data
$sql = "INSERT INTO tmp_mysqli_helper_test (name) VALUES (?),(?),(?)";
$stmt = prepared_query($conn, $sql, ['Sam','Bob','Joe']);
echo "Affected rows: $stmt->affected_rows\n";
echo "Last insert id: $conn->insert_id\n";

# Getting rows in a loop
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tmp_mysqli_helper_test WHERE id > ?";
$res = prepared_query($conn, $sql, [1])->get_result();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "{$row['id']}: {$row['name']}\n";
}

# Getting one row
$id  = 1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tmp_mysqli_helper_test WHERE id=?";
$row = prepared_query($conn, $sql, [$id])->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
echo "{$row['id']}: {$row['name']}\n";

# Update
$id = 1;
$new = 'Sue';
$sql = "UPDATE tmp_mysqli_helper_test SET name=? WHERE id=?";
$affected_rows = prepared_query($conn, $sql, [$new, $id])->affected_rows;
echo "Affected rows: $affected_rows\n";

# Getting an array of rows
$start = 0;
$limit = 10;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tmp_mysqli_helper_test LIMIT ?,?";
$all = prepared_query($conn, $sql, [$start, $limit])->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($all as $row)
{
    echo "{$row['id']}: {$row['name']}\n";
}
```

As you can see, a proper helper function can keep all the flexibility and readability of SQL and reduce the amount of code at the same time.

Comment: Okay, first that’s how I learned how to write a dynamic query. Second, thanks, I looked at your link and you really have some useful stuff there. Wish I knew about your site a long time ago. Back to the study desk.